# Chrome:Bookmarks jump back after dragging them to front position on the panel

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone come across this bug?

when I add a new bookmark, and drag it to the front position of the bookmark panel, then it jumped to back position?

then I drag again, but failed, is this a bug?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Moving unpinned tabs in Chrome.

Comment: @Xavierjazz what does that make it off topic?

Answer (score 0):

You have some bookmarks pinned and you are trying to move an unpinned bookmark to within the pinned bookmarks.